# How to put a song in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a game and I want to put a background song. I read that you have to put an mp3 in the raw folder, but I don't know where is it. Thanks.

Comment: "but I don't know where is it." - It belongs under the `/res` directory. If it's not there, you can create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the .mp3 file to the res folder.

[image]